# Drupal 8 Suddenly redirects to /core/install.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I was working on updating some contents on my website and suddenly it keeps redirect to www.example.com/core/install.php and gives me this message: "Drupal already installed" . I don't know what is the reason because it was working fine.

Comment: Check your mysql connection

Comment: It's most likely the mysql connection. More precisely it's maybe a problem to read DB connection credentials from settings.php. So check the file permissions of settings.php. Your web server should be able to read settings.php

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's file permission problem. Try to set the owner of the web-root of Drupal installation:

```
chown -R YOUR-USER:WEBSERVER-USER .
```

Especially it's file permission problem of the **settings.php**. If the web server can't read this file, the new install process is started and redirects to /core/install.php

If it helps so you can go on with more secure file permission setting described here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/244924

Answer (score 0):

Check the mysql value of max_allowed_packet.

```
max_allowed_packet = 64M
```

I know this is a late reply but folks can have a look here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2974321

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue as well. Our issue was a corrupted redis cache.
The fix for us was:

```
redis-cli FLUSHALL
```

Then restart redis.

Answer (score 0):

We have also seen this when you temporarily lose your connection to the database (MySQL in ours). My guess is that the code assumes that if you cannot see the database, by gosh you must be installing Drupal!